# Error con una condición de PHP

Tags: php

Alguien que me diga por favor por que se ejecuta el **ELSE** y no el **IF** cuando realmente existe la variable **page** en la url con un valor y aun así se ejecuta el **ELSE** será un error de xammp??.

la url esta asi = "http://localhost/Scroll%20PHP/api.php?page=1"

```
include_once "post.php";



if(isset($_GEt["page"])){


    $post = new Post();
    $page = $_GEt["page"];
    $data =  $post->getData($page);        
 

    echo json_encode($data);

}else{

    echo "No hay valor en en GET";

}
```

Comment: Corrige este typo: `$_GEt` y revisa de nuevo

Comment: no me funciono sigue igual amigo pensé que era eso pero no.

Comment: Agrega `var_dump($_GET);` para confirmar que realmente el valor está ahí.

Comment: Si sigue igual, a pesar del cambio sugerido por @BetaM, **nota que sólo cambiaste un caracter** con seguridad el caché **está pegado**. Agrega el var_dump que te sugiere Triby para que el cambio sea mayor.

Comment: Si lo hice amigo, por arte de magia parece que el error se corrigió realmente no se que era cunado volví y abrí el archivo ya funcionaba correctamente..

Comment: Suele ocurrir que cuando los cambios en los archivos de código php son poco significativos, **no son tomados por algún tiempo**, y parece como si operara algún caché. Personalmente, llevo bastante tiempo tratando de encontrarlo, para borrarlo a voluntad, pero no he dado con él.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con el siguiente código , me entrego el resultado esperado:

**header("Pragma: no-cache");** con esta instrucción prevenimos que el script sea almacenado en la cache del servidor y siempre cargue la ultima versión, perdón por no explicarlo antes.

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
$post = new stdClass();
$page = $_GET["page"];
$post->value= $page; 
echo json_encode(array("data"=>$post));
}else{
    echo "No hay valor en en GET";
}
?>
```